# How can I observe network traffic from my browser when using the Mac OS?

Tags: angularjs, macos, fiddler

I am used to using Visual Studio and Fiddler to watch network traffic on a PC environment to and from my AngularJS front-end. But now I started to use WebStorm.

Can someone tell me are there tools like Fiddler that run on the MacOS that can show me network traffic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly, I've not found a tool as nice as Fiddler since leaving the Windows environment.  I usually use Chrome Dev Tools network tab instead, though that's not quite as good.  There are a couple network monitoring tools, but the free ones I've tried were more at the packet level than at the HTTP level like Fiddler.

Answer (score 1):

From https://superuser.com/questions/42813/looking-for-http-debugging-proxy-for-mac-similar-to-fiddler-on-windows

> Use Chrome and navigate to chrome://net-internals/
>
> It allows detailed analysis and dumps.

Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

What about [chrome bandwith monitor](http://osxdaily.com/2013/07/05/monitor-web-bandwidth-usage-easily-with-chrome/)? It is tool built in chrome, but you would have to open your angularjs page only and disable extensions i guess.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about protocol analyzers (which allow you to sniff packets flying around on your network)?

If so, [WireShark](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/23765/wireshark) and [Packet Peeper](http://packetpeeper.org/) and [Cocoa Packet Analyzer](http://www.tastycocoabytes.com/cpa/) are available.  I think these all are free.